# Scroll pane on panel doesn't allow scrolling buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` that will contain either very few or a lot of buttons and if there are more buttons than can be displayed, I need to be able to scroll through the vertically displayed buttons. When I add a `JScrollPane` it doesn't let you scroll even when the buttons clearly overlap the available space of the `JPanel`.

How the scroll pane is created:

```
scrollPane = new ScrollPane(this);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));
```

How the buttons are added:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    panel.add(new TestButton("example." + i, "example"));
}
```

The panel is added onto another panel that is using `FlowLayout`. If it matters, the buttons are custom drawn buttons (they extend `JButton`) that change their own size (using `setPreferredSize`) and do their own drawing.

Comment: Since you are using a custom `JButton`, i.e. a class that extends `JButton` and you are overriding the drawing of the `JButton` as well as its preferred size, it is impossible for me to provide an answer since you have not provided the code of the custom button. For regular `JButton`s [@ArindamRoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166645/scroll-pane-on-panel-doesnt-allow-scrolling-buttons/63166959#63166959)'s answer is the way to go.

Comment: *If it matters, the buttons are custom drawn buttons (they extend JButton) that change their own size (using setPreferredSize) and do their own drawing.* - first get the code working properly with the standard JDK button. Then if that works, but it doesn't work with your custom button you know the problem is your custom button. If it doesn't work with the JDK button, then you have a simple [mre] top post. The code you posted tells us nothing and we can't guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow layout adds the components from left to right initially. As you disabled horizontal scrollbar, buttons are getting invisible. My suggestion is to have a box layout to place the buttons to be laid out top to bottom.

```
panel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(panel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: When I use that layout, the buttons get packed into tiny boxes despite their preferred size and despite the empty space available in the `JPanel`.

Comment: Is it possible to post a simplified test code? (May be in a single class with a JFrame, JScrollPane, JPanel and loop with JButtons). It will help me to figure out the issue.

Do u have preferred size too small for TestButton? If you use JButton, instead of custom TestButton, is there same issue?

Comment: box layout uses the minimum and maximum size of the components as well, set those values for your buttons to the same dimension to avoid shearing and allow scrolling